# C++ convert counted char const * data to double without using std::from_chars

Tags: c++, string, parsing, double

This problem is a programming issue, even though it is specific to the Raspberry Pi.  If the community thinks I should move this to the Pi specific Stack Exchange I can do so.

That said, the root cause of the problem is caused by what appears to be a failure to support non-integer types when using `std::from_chars()` with gcc on the Pi.  The following mcve shows the problem:

```
#include <charconv>

int main()
{
    char const *str = "1.23";
    int i = 0;
    std::from_chars_result result = std::from_chars(str, str + 4, i);
    double d = 0.0;
    result = std::from_chars(str, str + 4, d);
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles fine using MSVC on Windows 10, but generates the following error when I try with gcc `gcc (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1) 8.3.0` on the Pi, it's running buster-lite if it makes a difference.

```
g++ -c -std=c++17 check.c
check.c: In function ‘int main()’:
check.c:9:45: error: no matching function for call to ‘from_chars(const char*&, const char*, double&)’
     result = std::from_chars(str, str + 4, d);
```

The reason `std::from_chars` is such a natural choice is that in the production version, I'm working with a `std::string_view` and therefore do not have any guarantees that the data is NUL-terminated.  Therefore something like `strtod()` could potentially walk off the end of the data, and produce (best case) a misparse or (worst case) a program crash.

What other options do I have, if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options (off the top of my head; there are definitely others):

- Use a more modern version of gcc (specifically, a more modern libstdc++).
- copy the data into a `std::string` and then call `strtod` on the result of calling `c_str` on that string (which provides a null terminator).
- Manually copy the data into some array, and stuff a null at the end of it, then call `strtod`.

Comment: Due to implementation time constraints, I've gone with the second of your three options: using a temporary `std::string` and its `c_str()` results.  Not what I would have preferred, but it gets the job done.